# How can I access the controls in a listbox control generated by an itemtemplate

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a listbox and a dataTemplate defined like so:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="propertyTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="8" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="Chosen"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MAP}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"     Margin="388,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="522"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource propertyTemplate}"/>
```

I populate the listbox using a linq query:

```
Dim propertyList = (from a In db.properties
               select a).ToList()
listbox.datacontext = propertyList
```

I want to check and set the value of the "Chosen" checkbox for each item in the listbox.  Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it, bind `IsChecked` to a property on your item class, then iterate over your source list.

Comment: LinqtoSQL creates my item class, so I'm guessing that I'll need to create another class for this list which inherits from the LinqToSql class, and add a boolean field to it.  Would I have to create an item by item custom constructor in order to convert it to the new type, or is there a better way to do that? (Or am I just off in the wrong direction here)

Comment: You probably want to wrap your model (the database class) in a view-model class which has that additional property.

Comment: (The view-model class has a property containing the model, if that was not clear.)

Comment: I'm pretty green with this stuff still, so I'm looking up the MVVM pattern and how vb.net implements it.  Thanks for your help & patience.